# How can I create custom attribute to add a if.bind?

Tags: javascript, attributes, aurelia

I want to create an attribute to show or hide elements based on some global state.

Example:

```
<div state='new,unknown'>yadayadayada</div>
```

This attribute will then transform the div element to be effectively:

```
<div if.bind="['new','unknown'] | state & signal : 'state-change'">...</div>
```

The state value converter will convert the array to a boolean.

The goal is if the current global state is any of the provided states, then show the element else hide it.

I don't want a custom element with compose in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aurelia cheat sheet has an [example of naive-if custom attribute](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/8). I craft a solution based on it. The only differences are:

- The logic to calculate show or hide (of course)
- Subscribe to the global state too, instead of only `valueChanged`

Code:

```
import {BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot, customAttribute, templateController, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding';
import {State} from './state';

@customAttribute('naive-if')
@templateController
@inject(BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot, BindingEngine, State)
export class NaiveIf {
  constructor(viewFactory, viewSlot, bindingEngine, state) {
    this.show = false;
    this.viewFactory = viewFactory;
    this.viewSlot = viewSlot;
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    this.state = state;
  }

  bind() {
    this.updateView();
    this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this.state, 'value')
      .subscribe((newValue, oldValue) => this.updateView());
  }

  unbind() {
    if (this.subscription) this.subscription.dispose();
  }

  valueChanged(newValue) {
    this.updateView();
  }

  updateView() {
    let isShowing = this.show;
    let showStates = this.value.split(',');
    this.show = showStates.indexOf(this.state.value) != -1;

    if (this.show && !isShowing) {
      let view = this.viewFactory.create();
      this.viewSlot.add(view);
    } else if (!this.show && isShowing) {
      this.viewSlot.removeAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Or <strike>[GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=c82fa2e936466e98251fd0892da4c53c)</strike>

Comment: Your `GistRun` link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property and bind the `if` to that property. Like this:

```
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyViewModel {

  @computedFrom('something', 'someOtherValue')
  get globalState() {
     //do all conditions you need
     if (myArray.indexOf('something') != -1 && someOtherValue) {
       return true;
     }

     return false;
  }
}
```

Then you just have to bind:

```
<div if.bind="globalState"></div>
```

Comment: Then I have to import my global state in every model where I want to use it. So not my preferred solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if a custom attribute can simulate `if.bind`, because when it triggers, the element is already attached to DOM